# Error in tabs on java

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java, I need to do this exercise for school: 
Write a method that gets an array of numbers and returns an array with the index of the minimum and maximum values inside the array.
Example: for `int[] arr = {70,16,-3,5,90}`, the method will return `{2,4}`

My code is this:

```
public class MinAndMax {
    public static int main (String[] args) {

        int[] myArray = {2,7,32,89,32,1,56,73,99,3827,56};

        int min = myArray[0];
        int max = myArray[0];
        for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {

            if (myArray[i]<min) {
                min = myArray[i];
            }
            else if (myArray[i]>max) {
                max = myArray[i];
            }
        }
        int[] result = new int[2];
        result[0] = min;
        result[1] = max;

        return result;

    }
}
```

I don't understand the error message, I know I can't transform an `int` into an `int[]`, but I created a `new int[]` here, so I don't see the error.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: you have not written any function that does that, you just filled the `main` method where you cannot *return* anything. You even changed it to return int, which makes this not longer a valid main method. You need to get clear on how your code is supposed to be invoked. Are you submitting it online, etc.? Note that your code itself is not returning the indices of minmax, but the values of minmax.

Comment: I get the error message : incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int

Comment: So how can I create a new array with the values I want to input into it ?

Comment: `main` method shouldn't return anything. Defined entry point of Java application is `public static **void** main (String[] args){...}`. Also you defined that method to return `int` but you are returning `int[]`. What is returned must match to what is *declared* to be returned from method.

Comment: I'll try to recode it from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You should not return result array like that. Because you are writing that inside the void main function.
you code should do something like below,

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class MinAndMax
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] myArray = {2,7,32,89,32,1,56,73,99,3827,56};

        int min = myArray[0];
        int max = myArray[0];
        for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {

            if (myArray[i]<min) {
                min = myArray[i];
            }
            else if (myArray[i]>max) {
                max = myArray[i];
            }
        }
        int[] result = new int[2]; 
        result[0] = min;
        result[1] = max;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all

I added import java.util.Arrays and used Arrays.toString method and it works

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You get the error `incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int` because the `main` method has a `int` return type but you return `int[]`.

To resolve the problem, use the standard `main` method signature `public static void main (String[] args)` since this allows the compiler to run the `main` method when you run the `.java` file.

To print the min and max values, you could extract the logic for finding min and max values to a separate method (e.g., `getMinAndMaxValueIndices`) and call it from the `main` method:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int[] minAndMaxValues = getMinAndMaxValues();
        // print individual elements
        int min = minAndMaxValues[0];
        int max = minAndMaxValues[1];
        System.out.println("min="+min+"\n"); // prints min=1
        System.out.println("max="+max+"\n"); // prints max=3827
        // print the array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(minAndMaxValues)); // prints [1, 3827]

    } 

    private static int[] getMinAndMaxValues() {
        int[] myArray = {2,7,32,89,32,1,56,73,99,3827,56};

        int min = myArray[0];
        int max = myArray[0];
        for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {

            if (myArray[i]<min) {
                min = myArray[i];
            }
            else if (myArray[i]>max) {
                max = myArray[i];
            }
        }
        int[] result = new int[2]; 
        result[0] = min;
        result[1] = max;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help
I added import java.util.Arrays and used the Arrays.toString method and it works

Thanks

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to accept an answer if it solved your problem and to upvote answers that you found useful since this helps others find useful answers faster :)